# I have a map that i want to delete entries from by value

Tags: scala

I have a map(WeakHashMap) that i am using for some caching. I want to delete some entries from the map depending on the value.
I am unable to figure out a way to do this.

Comment: that's very vague, can you show an example of what you tried and why it doesn't work?

Comment: Well i cant understand what approach to take for this. For that reason i do not have anything to add. Basically i have a map where i want to delete some entries by value and not by key.

Comment: You are using a wrong data structure for the job.

Comment: @n.m.  So i want a collection where i can insert strings by defined positions. Also i want to be able to delete certain values from those positions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way is to use filter and filter based on the key.  This will create a new Map and not modify the original.

```
val newMap = map.filter((key, value) => <true/false based on value>)
```

If it is possible to structure your application to work with this I would recommend it.

If you need to delete elements from a mutable map (modifying the original instead of creating a new map you should use foldLeft to loop over your map and create a list of the keys corresponding to the values you want to remove

```
val keyList = map.foldLeft(List[KeyType]())((keys, pair) => if(pair._2 <should be removed>) pair._1 :: keys else keys)
keyList.foreach(map.remove)
```

pair is a tuple of the current element _1 is the key, _2 is the value